# Code structure and execution

Tags: ios, swift

I have been working with Swift now for about 6-8 months, and I am struggling with the proper way to structure code that needs to execute in order. When I do this now code will not be completed in `stepToRunFirst()` that sets variables for `stepToRunSecond()`. Ideally I would like to structure the code like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

     stepToRunFirst()

     stepToRunSecond()
}
```

Instead though i'm forced to execute this way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

     stepToRunFirst()
}

func stepToRunFirst()

     //do whatever

     stepToRunSecond()
}
```

I feel like it makes the code much more difficult to read, and maintain, this way. Is this the correct way to structure it, or is there a better way?

Comment: In your first version, both functions *are* called sequentially. Why do you think that *"code is not completed ... that sets variables"* ?

Comment: This feels like something in `stepToRunFirst` is asynchronous and (obviously) isn't happening until after it's returned and `stepToRunSecond` has been invoked.

Comment: I agree with Steve Wilford. Also, that is a fine way to structure your code, although you could rename it to beginSteps or something like that to make it more obvious that more steps are being run. If you have asynchronous stuff going on then you need to do it like that.

Comment: @SteveWilford: But that would not explain why the second version (where `stepToRunSecond()` is called right before `stepToRunFirst()` returns) works as expected.

Comment: @MartinR Unless `//do whatever` is a `dispatch_async`

Comment: @SteveWilford: There would only be a difference if stepToRunSecond() is called within a completion handler somewhere inside stepToRunFirst, and not as the last statement. If the two variants are really as shown in the question then there is no difference.

Comment: Thank you all for contributing your comments. Yes, some of the code is executed with "InBackgroundWithBlock", which I now understand is asynchronous. Maybe a better way to ask the question would be is there a way to make asynchronous code complete before the next step is executed (i.e. making in synchronous)?